# ASP.NET - modifying controller class variable using controller method

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm starting to learn C# and I'm stuck with a little problem.
I have a controller variable as below:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // Empty List
    List<Something> FilteredSomethingLists = new List<Something>();
```

Then I have a `IActionResult` Method in the Controller like so:

```cs
public IActionResult Filter(string Attribute1, string Attribute2, int page)
{
    // TestModel will create a list with random data, then filter the list with 
    // (Attribute1 and 2, then add to the FilteredSomethingLists
    foreach (Something p in TestModel.FilterSomething(Attribute1, Attribute2)) 
    {
        FilteredSomethingLists.Add(p);
    }

    ...

    // Display some result on the first page
    return View(...);
}
```

In the Filter method above, the `TestModel` will first create a list with random Something values, and then the `FilterSomething` method will filter out some `SomethingObj` from the list with the given attributes, then those objects are added into the `FilteredSomethingLists`. I have called the Filter method in `Filter.cshtml`, and the objects in the `FilteredSomethingLists` are perfectly shown on the webpage.

However, when I have another method:

```cs
public IActionResult Paging(int page)
{
    Console.WriteLine(FilteredSomethingLists[0].SomeAttribute);
    
    ...
    
    return View(...);
}
```

There is nothing shown on the webpage, also nothing on the console output, which means the `FilteredSomethingLists` is still empty, even after calling the Filter method.

I am doing so because I want to do pagination on the `FilteredSomethingLists`, but calling the `Filter` method with different page number value again will generate a whole new `SomethingLists` by the `TestModel`, so I guess I could display the first page of `FilteredSomethingLists` by calling `Filter`, then call `Paging` for the next pages so that I can avoid to re-initialised the `FilteredSomethingLists`. However it did not work.

Answer (score 2):

Web is stateless so information will not persist between requests. If you need to filter a list, then you will need to reconstruct server side and return the filtered list. Another option is to pass the list back to the server through a POST request and then filter, but that will be heavier on the traffic back to the server.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Paging(PagingRequest request)
{
    var FilteredSomethingLists = constructFilteredList(request);
    Console.WriteLine(FilteredSomethingLists[0].SomeAttribute);
    
    ...
    
    return View(...);
}
```

This is just an example of what could be done. Your filtered list function would be a Linq query that takes your input parameters and then filters the result set from the database. You can use the fluent API or inline Linq.

To handle different pages, Linq has a [Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.skip?view=netcore-3.1) and [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.take?view=netcore-3.1) function on `IQueryable`. The number you skip would be the page number multiplied by the items per page. Then you would `Take` the number of items per page.

Comment: Not sure if I am on the right track, but I have created a new Repository class under Models, and try to do the contructFilteredList work over there. (Couldnt figure out how to modify the old Models as I am not familiar with interface and stuffs)